# Applications running in task manager

Tags: android

I have finished running an application and came out of it. But still that application is in the task manager. What does it mean ? please help

Comment: What does "finished" mean? Just because an Activity has been closed it does not mean the Apllication VM is shutdown completely. That is a feature of Android. It is not a failure of your app.

Answer (score 0):

According to the activity lifecycle ([Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)), when you close your activity it enters a "paused" state (calls OnPause). It remains like this until forced closed, or the device runs out of memory and kills it. At this point, OnStop and OnDestroy will be called, and it will not appear in the Task Manager.

Whilst in this paused state, if resumed from the task manager, OnResume only will be called (and not OnCreate) so put into OnResume the code you need to handle this event. NOTE, both OnCreate and OnResume (along with OnStart) will be called when starting your app from scratch.